# NSBundle cannot recognize recent unzip files

Tags: ios, zip, nsbundle

I have a zip file to contain all necessary text files in my project. When the app launched for the first time, I unzipped file using ZipArchive. Then when I tried to locate one of my unzipped file to open using:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[engViDictionaryStore stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType:[engViDictionaryStore pathExtension]]];
```

The app crashed with an exception 
`"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'".` However, when I launch the app for second time, it could locate unzipped files and works well.

I want to ask if there is anyway for NSBundle recognises my unzipped files right after unzip them.

Comment: Show us how you are unzipping the file in case there is a thread issue or something similar

Comment: Unzipped bundle files can/would not become part of the bundle. They must be extracted somewhere else like documents directory. See where the files are being unzipped & use that path.

Comment: @TommyBs I unzipped file in method applicationDidBecomeActive:, so I don't think that thread issue.
ZipArchive *zipArchive = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
[zipArchive UnzipOpenFile:zipFilePath];
[zipArchive UnzipFileTo:bundlePath overWrite:YES];
[zipArchive UnzipCloseFile];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bundle cannot be changed or modified once app has been deployed|installed [even during testing].

You must extract the files into some other directory most probably `documents` directory & access your files form there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That really makes a trick. Just want to make it clear, you said the bundle cannot be changed/modified once app deployed, but in case I launch my app second time, the NSBundle can find my unzipped resources. Why?

Comment: i am sure those resources are not located inside bundle. It just cannot be done given apple's public APIs. If you look further into the issue, you might find the correct location of unzipped files.